# how to place video inside of an image

Tags: video

Very new to blender so be gentle. I am more looking for a direction to follow then an exact how to but obviously that would be useful as well.

**Problem:** 
I am creating a YouTube intro sequence for my gaming community and one of the idea I have is to make the camera pull back from our clan logo.

While its doing this I'd like to have small sequences of recorded gameplay appearing within or almost reflecting off logo until the entire logo is revealed, something [like this GoW clip](https://youtu.be/WB3BpDyPlLI?t=225) (3:46-3:51)

Is this possible, and if so what area should I be researching to make it happen?

Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: very new to blender? Start here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: what render engine are you using?

Comment: I have swaped between Blender Render and Cycles render testing each of them out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use video or image sequence exactly the same way like texture.

In Node editor:
"Shift + A" -> "Texture" -> "Image sequence" (select all images "image.000" - "image.xxx").

Or you can choose "Texture" and open video file exactly like image.

Now you can setup video texture offset and start frame. 
Start frame: when video start playing (timeline frames)
Offset: set first frame where video start play (video texture frames)

Example:
You need start playing video texture on frame 1250 of your animation and you want to jump on 10th second in your video texture. (remove first 10 second from video texture)

Set Start frame to 1250
Set offset to 240 (for 24FPS: 24 x 10 second)

There are also "Frames" - you can use it for stop play video texture. Frames = video texture frames, not your animation frames on timeline.

Second option is using Material ID for creating mask and add video to object using this mask in Video Sequence Editor or in Compositor.

Personally I thing the 1st option is easiest way how to do it, just play with setup to achieve what you need. :-)

Comment: It took me awhile but I believe i have made it work using your first option. thank you.  
The only problem I am having now is scaling down the video to appear correctly in the available space. I corrected this for now by enlarging the area but I am curious if there is a better way.  [Here is a link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/otpg8d7szog6ucm/0001-0240.avi?dl=0) of what I have so far  using trial footage. I would like to either place different footage in each of the 3 workable areas or simply keep it as is.

(I'm sorry for the formatting, I have re-posted this comment 15 times with no change)

Comment: As a first you need to unwrap object (as you know :-) ) In this case I recommend use "Project from view" while you look at object through camera (zero on numpad) This make rights coordinates for you. Now in material you can add: "Shift +A" -> "Vector" -> "Mapping" and "Shift +A" -> "Input" -> Texture coordinate.   For better Imaginations: https://postimg.org/image/pdv93dss1/